# Is the integral identity $\int d x \, f(x) \, \, g(f(x))' \, = \, 0$ true?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

We have a positive function $f$ on a certain N-dimensional domain $E \subset  \mathbb{R}^N$, namely $f(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\in E$. The function is such that $f(x)=0$ on the boundary, when $x \in \partial E$.
We also require that

$$
\int_E d^Nx \, f(x)  \, = \, F >0
$$
is finite.

Given a "well behaved" function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
how to prove that  (feel free to assume all the nice continuity properties you want for both $f$ and $g$)

$$
\int_E d^Nx \, f(x) \, \nabla \, g(f(x)) \, = \, 0 \quad ?
$$

*Attempt:* probably the N-dimensional domain is a complication and it is possible to just consider the 1D case. If $g$ is the identity, by using the integration by parts we have
$$
\int_E dx \, f \, \partial_x \, f \,=-\int_E dx \, (\partial_x f) \,  \, f 
$$
so in this simple case the statement is true. A similar argument holds also when $g(f) = f^a$ for some real power $a\neq -1$ such that the integrals are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the 1D case. We have
$$
\int_a^b f(x) (g(f(x)))' \, dx = -\int_a^b f'(x) g(f(x)) \, dx
$$
We can set $u = f(x)$, so that $du = f'(x) dx$, giving
$$
\int_a^b f(x) (g(f(x)))' \, dx = - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(u) du = -\int_{0}^0 g(u) \, du = 0
$$
Thus, we have established the result in the 1D case for "nice" functions.

With some care we can play essentially the same trick in multiple dimensions. Observe that
$$
\int_E f(x) \nabla (g(f(x)) \, d^N x =
\begin{pmatrix}
\int_E f(x) \partial_{x_1} (g(f(x)) \, d^N x \\
\vdots \\
\int_E f(x) \partial_{x_n} (g(f(x)) \, d^N x 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But now we can write
\begin{align}
\int_E f(x) \partial_{x_i} (g(f(x)) \, d^N x
&= \int \cdots \int f(x) \partial_{x_i} (g(f(x)) \, dx_1 \ldots dx_n
\\&= \int \cdots \int f(x) \partial_{x_i} (g(f(x)) \, dx_i dx_1 \ldots dx_{i - 1} dx_{i + 1} \ldots dx_n
\end{align}
And, just as in the 1D case, we have
$$
\int f(x) \partial_{x_i} (g(f(x)) \, dx_i = -\int g(f(x)) \partial_{x_i} f(x) \, dx_i = 0
$$
Thus, it is indeed the case that
$$
\int_E f(x) \nabla (g(f(x)) d^N x = 0
$$
if $f$ vanishes on the boundary and $f$ and $g$ are suitably nice (so that we can apply Fubini's theorem, integrate by parts, and change variables).

Comment: The OP assumes that $f$ vanishes on the boundary of the domain of integration, which means that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ in your example. Hence the last integral is indeed zero for any $g$.

Comment: Oh you're right. As usual, my first pass at a math SE post is not correct.

Comment: Is the cange of variable to $u$ a legit change of variable? $f$ is not a bijection (it is zero on the boundary and possibly in some isolated point in the interior)

Comment: The one-dimensional change of variables is quite generally true as long as it is applied carefully. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable. Set $G' = g$. Then $\int_a^b f'(x) g(f(x)) dx = \int_a^b G'(f(x)) f'(x) dx = \int_a^b (G\circ f)'(x) dx = G(f(b)) - G(f(a))$. On the other hand $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(u) du = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} G'(u) du = G(f(b))- G(f(a))$. Hence $\int_a^b f'(x) g(f(x)) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(u) du$.

Comment: In the multidimensional case, you're right that we need additional hypotheses to change variables. Usually we ask that the change of variables is injective and continuously differentiable, although weaker hypotheses are possible. We also have to set $dx = |\det D \phi  (u) |du$ where $x = \phi (u)$ is the change of variables. The necessity of the absolute value signs also routinely complicates things.

Comment: Very clear, many thanks, +1. I was thinking to slice the domain, so to perform first a 1D integral.

Comment: @Quillo I think that's a good idea. Something like that might be able to work.

Comment: @Quillo I've put up an answer. It occurs to me that we might have to restrict $E$ somehow. However, since $f$ vanishes on the boundary, it might not be necessary as long as $E$ is compact. Just enclose $E$ in a rectangle and throw in an indicator function. But I'll leave it to more skilled analysts to make any definite comments in that direction.